# How do I create multiple linked lists?

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

Basically, I need 7 linked lists which hold the same types of data. How do I go about this? I am not experienced in C, I know how to create a linked list with a Structure. But how do I create 7 linked lists? Do I need 7 structures?

Comment: You most likely do.

Comment: how would you store 7 different numbers? it's the same principle

Comment: "Do I need 7 structures?" because your lists hold the same type you have to define only _one_ time the supporting structs and functions, and that independently if you will create 7 lists or any other number of them. If you need to open 7 files you use the same type FILE, not FILE1, FILE2 ... FILE7 ... fortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each list is made out of nodes. Each node is a struct. so each node in each list is a struct.
the typical node looks like this:

```
struct node
{
   struct node* next;
   struct node* prev;
   int data; /*can be int char char* void* and so on depending on the type of data you want to store*/
};
```

the next node will store a pointer to the next node in that list. the prev will store a pointer to the previous node in the list.

Now - if you need to store 7 same type elements in one list it will contain 7 nodes - 7 structs.

Hope this helps